# Using Runtime shared libraries in an application with multiple modules (Flex)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I have an application with several modules. Without RSL's they are working fine, only issue being it becomes slow and thus loss in terms of time performance.  With RSL's size gets reduced and also the performance improves but some modules don't get loaded. Any idea over this ? Can't we use RSL in an application with multiple modules ?

Any help in this regard would be greatlt appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using or not using RSL shouldn't affect performance. Probably it's just that some modules won't work without RSL increasing that way the performance.

That said, suing RSL is a good practice. Make sure all the RSL are loaded before the definitions they include are invoked (i.e use a preload strategy or just include all the RSL definitions in the "main" SWF).

If an attempt of retrieving RSL definition from within a module is made while the RSL is not loaded yet it will stop the script. That's probably what's happening now...